# How should an application add/remove scopes to an existing grant?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth, oauth2client

Tried adding additional scopes using oauth2client's OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets via the scopes parameter.

I believe users of an application would prefer to gradually expand privileges; as its needed, and as trust forms...

What is the best way to add/expand/remove scopes when the application has an existing grant? Revoke and reauthorize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do that. You will need to re-authorize the user. I agree that it would be nice to incrementally add scopes, but you will still need to show an authorization page, so I think you won't gain much doing that.

Comment: Any thoughts on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629939/is-there-a-deep-dive-on-googles-oauth2-scopes ?